# Stuck while figuring out the Bookings model for my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a ticket booking app as my sample project using Ruby on Rails 4.1. Three are three models - Events, Tickets and Bookings. Events have many tickets and bookings. Tickets have many bookings and they belong to events. Bookings belongs to events and tickets.

Now, I am modelling the app closely along the lines of Eventbrite. In particular, the ticket booking pages will look like this https://www.eventbrite.com/e/bacon-and-beer-classic-july-26-2014-tickets-11729347795?err=29

Here's where I'm stuck. I initially figured that the Bookings show page will list the ticket tiers with a dropdown to select the number of tickets. Then, the user upon clicking the pay button will be redirected to the new Bookings page where he/she will complete the order.

However, I can't figure out how to carry that dropdown data to the bookings page. That's one issue. The second issue is to figure out a way to calculate the total amount when the user picks more than one ticket and display that in the new bookings page for checkout.

Sorry if this question sounds too dumb. I'm just wondering if this could be achieved using Ruby/Rails methods and helpers or if javascript is needed to get this done.

Comment: Seems like you could do it without javascript.

Comment: The dropdown data would be implemented by a select helper (see this documentation http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html )

Comment: Hi - can you please edit your question and add the relevant code? that way we can tell you what you might need to change to make it work. :)